# Pandas "<=" operator unexpected behaviour for datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I do have an analytics event table with column `event_datetime`

I want to filter out pandas table for only 2 days, for example, Feb 1st and 2nd:

```
event_data.loc[(event_data['event_datetime'] >= '2023-02-01') &(event_data['event_datetime'] <= '2023-02-02')]
```

But this code does return events for 2023-02-01 only, although I wrote less of equal '2023-02-02'.

In sql it works fine. Do I miss something? Did not find anything about it in pandas docs...

Comment: What's the dtype of that column? Pandas handles `<=` differently for strings and dates.

Comment: event_date['event_datetime'] would have to be a string with all dates in the same format as those you compare ie 'YYYY-MM-DD' (or '%Y-%m-%d' in python parlance). If your column contains datetime types it will crash. If it contains date strings in different format, it will return unexpected results.

Comment: @GalodoLeste, thank you. The problem was exactly with datetime format - it was not converted in str properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Galo do Leste and @Nick ODell hint, the problem was with datetime format of the column - it was not properly converted into str format.

So if column has datetime type - operator `<=` doesnt work as it expected.
After proper column casting to string format

```
event_data['event_datetime'] = event_data['event_datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

- it works fine.

Comment: Just a note when comparing dates that are expressed as strings. The order of string MUST by year then month then day. Remember that python only sees a string when doing the comparison and has no concept of date or time. "31-01-1999' will be greater than '2023-12-31' when compared as strings.